# Copy data from Offscreen-plain to Render target

Tags: rendering, directx, render, directx-9

What am I doing wrong?

I want to create multisampled render target with bitmap from image.

My plan is:

1. Create `render target` and `offscreen-plain` surfaces
2. Fill `offscreen` surface with bitmap
3. Use `StretchRect` to copy data from `offscreen-plain` to `render target`

```cpp
IDirect3DSurface9* targetSurface;
IDirect3DSurface9* sourceSurface;

device->CreateRenderTarget(width, height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DMULTISAMPLE_4_SAMPLES, 0, false, &targetSurface, NULL);
device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(width, height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &sourceSurface, NULL);

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
sourceSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect, NULL, 0);
// Writing data...
sourceSurface->UnlockRect();

// Copy image content to render target
device->StretchRect(sourceSurface, NULL, targetSurface, NULL, D3DTEXF_POINT);
```

But the rendered result is not what I expect.

[image: Wrong rendered texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the wrong bitmap filling.

RenderTarget size is power of two.

Also, offscreen-plain is redundant, so the code is following:

```cpp
IDirect3DSurface9* surface;

device->CreateRenderTarget(width, height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DMULTISAMPLE_4_SAMPLES, 0, true, &surface, NULL);

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
surface->LockRect(&lockedRect, NULL, 0);
// Writing data...
surface->UnlockRect();
```